# Copy file from HDFS to local directory from within Java Code when run using spark-submit in cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am working on a java program where some code generates a file and stores it on some HDFS path. Then, I need to bring that file on the local machine storage/NAS and store it there. I am using the below for the same:

```
Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf);
Path srcPath = new Path("/some/hdfs/path/someFile.csv");;
Path destPath = new Path("file:///data/output/files/");
hdfs.copyToLocalFile(false, newReportFilePath, destPath, false);
```

This gives me below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/data/output (exists=false, cwd=file:/data7/yarn/some/other/path)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2123)
    .
    .
    .
```

Below is the command used to run the java application

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ..............
```

I am new to Spark/Hadoop but from other couple of questions on SO and web, it seems that since its running in cluster mode, any machine can act as a driver and `FileSystem.copyToLocalFile` will point to any machine which will be acting as a driver.

Any suggestions on how I can bring that csv file to local machine would be appreciated.